# Highcharts: Remove left and right padding in column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart with adjusted `pointPlacements`, `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` and a datetime x-axis with a `max` and `min` value.

The expected behavior would be that the chart is cut on the min and max value of the axis, but Highcharts seems to extend the x-axis to the left an right over those extremes by about half the data-interval each. ([See image](https://i.imgur.com/h1mNd3S))

I tried about everything I found in the API Reference but couldn't get rid of that extra space on the sides.

Things I already tried:
* setting `xAxis.minPadding` / `xAxis.maxPadding` to `0` with and w/o `startOnTick` / `endOnTick`
* setting `xAxis.ceiling` / `x.axis.floor` to the `max` / `min` value
* setting `xAxis.margin` to 0
* setting `xAxis.softMax` and `xAxis.softMin` instead of `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max`
* using`pointStart` / `pointInterval` instead of x-values within the data
* setting `chart.spacing` to `[0,0,0,0]`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d4rz572L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly set `min` and `max` properties:

```
xAxis: [{
    type: "datetime",
    // pointRange = 1530792000000 - 1530770400000
    min: 1530748800000 + (21600000 / 2),
    max: 1530835200000 - (21600000 / 2)
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8bqt1chn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange

Comment: So if I want the chart to start on the 5th of July at 0:00 and I have 6 hour intervals, I actually have to set the 5th of July at 3:00 as the starting point? Well that's just straight up not intuitive at all ^^ 
If it's stupid, but it works it ain't stupid ...I guess :D

Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Just tried to implement your solution. Problem for my use case is that I use the axis `max` and `min` at other points in my code (e.g. `tickPositioner`) as well. So I now would have to take that change of the `max` and `min` value into consideration every time, which is of course possible, but tedious.

Comment: The solution that worked for me was setting the `pointRange` of the column series to 0.
This ensures that highcharts thinks that the columns width is 0 and therefore it doesn't add padding to the sides of the chart.