# Highcharts line chart with very large padding on x Axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a simple line chart with HighCharts with a very simple x axis, a start and an end value - however all charts I make with just these two points have a very wide padding on each side of the shown lines.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Wixxr/t2Lhmbuf/4/

I've tried almost all options I could find in the documentation on x axis, I've tried settings offsets, specific points, specific ticks, a negative margin, a width of 200%, a combination of multiple settings, you name it: I've tried it, but I can't get it to work.

I can't use specific sizes since the container it's in (the overlaying `div`) will be resized responsively, but even in the fiddle where the container has a fixed size the large padding is visible.

Searched for it, but I think I'm using the wrong keywords, since I can't find anything related to this.

Comment: It's counterintuitive, but in order to have zero padding you have to set `xmin:0.5` and `xmax:0.5` for `xAxis`; the first 0.5 is 0 + `pointRange/2`, the second is 1 - `pointRange/2`, where `pointRange` is 1 for your category axis. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57821344/16466946) for a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding results from the fact that you are using `category` axis type. Points by default are placed in the center of category, to change that, set:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      ...,
      pointPlacement: 'on'
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/an40gbL3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointPlacement

Comment: Odd, never would have thought to look there, but it works!